# Unable to build gradle project in intellij, visual studio code and eclipse IDEs

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

```
Build file 'C:\BAT\bulk-action-tool-bdd\build.gradle' line: 2

Plugin [id: 'io.qameta.allure', version: '2.8.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'io.qameta.allure', version: '2.8.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.qameta.allure:io.qameta.allure.gradle.plugin:2.8.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:213)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$4(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:146)
    at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:207)
    at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:201)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolvePluginRequests(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:144)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:84)
```

I have tried in multiple ways by adding correct java version and correct gradle version and have installed some plugins still the issue is same need to resolve the issue